# UNC Path not supported when trying to run batch file from a server

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm writing a script to have preset bookmarks automatically import themselves into Google Chrome and I am trying to copy the contents of a folder from a shared server (the bookmarks file) to a computer that the server is connected to and I'm getting the following error:

```
'\\zapp\pc\PLI'
CMD.EXE was not started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
The command was completed successfully. 

Invalid Path 
0 File(s) copied
z: was deleted successfully.
```

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
net use z: \\zapp\pc
xcopy "Z:\PLI\" "c:\installers\" /e /c /i /q /h /r /y
net use z: /delete /y

goto :bookmarks

REM Imports bookmarks to the bookmark bar
REM User has to manually enable the bookmark bar and disable autofill
:bookmarks
xcopy "c:\installers\bookmarks" "c:%LOCALAPPDATA%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\*" /Y
echo Bookmarks Copied. Use ctrl+shift+b to show the bookmarks bar and double check that all bookmarks work!
echo Turn off autofill and saved passwords in chrome://settings
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

REM Shutdown computer
echo Press any key to shutdown the computer
pause
shutdown -s -t 0
```

and then I'm receiving further errors about none of the files being copied, But it seems like it keeps trying to switch directories and therefore isn't finding the files that I want to copy. Is there a simple fix for this? Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong: `"c:%LOCALAPPDATA%`.  The variable already has the drive letter in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you think that's why the UNC Error is being thrown? Would removing `%LOCALAPPDATA%` from the script solve that issue?  It seems like the error is getting thrown before that on line 3 `xcopy "Z:\PLI\" "c:\installers\" /e /c /i /q /h /r /y`